# How to pass parameters to css classes

Tags: html, css

I want to know is it possible to add some flexibility to css via this:

```
<div class='round5'></div>
```

where `.round` is a class with round corners and '5' determines the amount of radius. Is it possible? I have seen some where, but I don't know how the implementation takes place.

Comment: The css classes must be defined manually.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

For anyone stumbling across this in 2018, [whilst not fully supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20var) CSS variables now give you the ability to pass a variable directly into your class.

```
<div class="round" style="--radius: 100%;"></div>
<style>
  .round {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #BADA55;
    border-radius: var(--radius);
  }
</style>
```

You can also define root variables and pass them in as well

```
<div class="round" style="--radius: var(--rad-50);"></div>
<style>
  :root {
    --rad-0: 0%;
    --rad-50: 50%;
    --rad-100: 100%;
  }
  .round {
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #BADA55;
    border-radius: var(--radius);
  }
</style>
```

This is also scoped to the element as well. If you set the `--radius` in one element is wont effect another element. Pretty jazzy right!

Comment: Does anybody know if this can be used with typestyle?

Comment: @Javiere I think what you might be looking for is [theming](https://typestyle.github.io/#concept-theming). I'm more familiar with these concepts in [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) but you should be able to change your theme per components to have them render differently.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This must be resulting in inline css issue, when used with well configured CSP header.

Answer (score 13):

You can't define the border radius separate from its value because it's all one property. There's no way to tell an element to have rounded corners "in general" without also specifying how much to round them by.

However, you can do something kind of similar with multiple classes and different properties:

HTML:

```
<div class="rounded blue"></div>
<div class="rounded green"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.rounded {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
.green {
    background: green;
}
```

The `.rounded` class adds the border radius and the `.blue` and `.green` classes add the background color.

(I like to name and order the classes such that they read logically, like `<div class="large box"></div>`, etc.).

Answer (score 12):

Here is an answer that I came up with that requires a small amount of jQuery, and a small knowledge of Regex.

```js
    $(function() {
      var number = $("div").attr("class").match(/\d+$/);
      $("div").css({
        "width": "100px",
        "height": "100px",
        "background-color": "green",
        "border-radius": number + "px"
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='round54'>hello</div>
```

The `.match()` function uses Regex. Regex is used to detect parts of strings. The `\d` detects any digits. The `+` matches the previous selector 1 or more times. In other words, the number can be a multi digit number. And the `$` means it has to be at the end.

So then the jQuery uses that in the `border-radius` property later. All you have to do is append `px`, and you are good to go.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfzqJ/1/)

Comment: Could you use this approach but write anew class name to the DOM? For example `class="round round5"`

Answer (score 6):

You can use multiclassing on the element. Eg.:

HTML:

```
<div class="round">Box without border radius</div>
<div class="round rounded-5">Box with 5px border radius</div>
<div class="round rounded-10">Box with 10px border radius</div>
```

CSS:

```
.round {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.round.rounded-5 {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.round.rounded-10 {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do something similar but not exactly the way you've put it.

CSS

```
.radius{
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.r5{
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="radius">Hello World</div>
<br/>
<div class="radius r5">Hello World</div>
```

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/dSzqH/)**

In the example above the red border will be retained but the border-radius will change.

Note that you don't start class names with numbers, hence `r5` rather than `5`

Answer (score 4):

you can do this. but you have to create the css in the html document(not linked, but between the `<style>` tag). you can use php or javascript to make a loop. for example try this:

```
<style>
    <?php
    $round = 5;
    for ($round = 50; $round <= 150; $round+=25){

   echo "#round$round{
       height: 300px;
       width: 300px;
       background: #f00;

border-radius : ".$round."px;
    margin: 2px;
}
";

    }
    ?>
</style>
<?php 
for ($round=50;$round<=150; $round+=25){

    echo "<div id='round$round'>

</div>
            ";

}

?>
```

hope this helps! :D

Comment: If you want to make it dynamic (not reload), you have to use javascript to make it.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe what you want is like this

CSS

```
.round {
  border-radius: 4px; /*it's default when you juse using .round*/
}
.round.five {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.round.ten {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="round five">something</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are saying but you would have to reserve the keyword "round" for only this purpose. If you look at the following.

```
div[class*="round"] {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

And then targeting specific variants of it using...

```
div[class="round5"] {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The first block of code selects all class names which contain the word round, this can be both a good thing and a bad thing.

Comment: This may work, however there's already far cleaner and less potentially backfiring ways of doing this listed.....

Comment: True but it the right circumstances this solution might be the right or only approach.

Answer (score 1):

By following the solution by @stwilz and with the accordance of the CSS var() function usage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties. I was able to make use it as this

```
.round{
    border-radius: var(--radius, 10px); 
    /* 10px as default value */
}
```

Then can be use like this

```
<div class="round">Hello</div>
<div class="round" style="--radius: 20px">Hello</div>
```

Instead of default value, global value can be set as

```
:root{
    --radius: 30px;
}
```