# CSS property value from class name

Tags: css, css-selectors

It is possible to pass parameters for CSS in class name? For example:

```css
.mrg-t-X {
   margin-top: Xpx;
}
```

```
<span class="mrg-t-10">Test</span>
```

In this example X should be 10.

Comment: No. But you can use attributes.

Comment: Can you give me the example please? `<span class="mrg-t" mrg="10">Test</span>`

Comment: Hmm.. now I think of it.. I think that only goes for `content`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Answer (score 10):

No it isn't. The closest we have to this is the [`attr()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content), but that only works within the `content` property:

```css
figure::before {
  content: attr(data-before) ', ';
}

figure::after {
  content: attr(data-after) '!';
}
```

```html
<figure data-before="Hello" data-after="world"></figure>
```

Perhaps one day this will be expanded so that we can use it elsewhere, but for now this isn't possible.

Currently as I'm sure you're aware if you want to be able to use the `.mrg-t-X` class, you'll need to define separate style rules for each `X` you wish to allow:

```css
.mrg-t-1 { ... }
.mrg-t-2 { ... }
.mrg-t-3 { ... }
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Nowdays you can use [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) inside a style attribute instead generating a specific class:

> Custom properties (sometimes referred to as CSS variables or cascading variables) are entities defined by CSS authors that contain specific values to be reused throughout a document. They are set using custom property notation (e.g., `--main-color: black;`) and are accessed using the `var()` function (e.g., `color: var(--main-color);`).
>
> Complex websites have very large amounts of CSS, often with a lot of repeated values. For example, the same color might be used in hundreds of different places, requiring global search and replace if that color needs to change. Custom properties **allow a value to be stored in one place**, then referenced in multiple other places. An additional benefit is semantic identifiers. For example, `--main-text-color` is easier to understand than `#00ff00`, especially if this same color is also used in other contexts.
>
> Custom properties are subject to the cascade and inherit their value from their parent.

example

```css
  span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: var(--m-t);
}

html {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, 10px, lightgrey 10px, lightgrey 20px);} /* see 10px steps  */
```

```html
<span style="--m-t:50px">one</span>
<span style="--m-t:85px">two</span>
<span style="--m-t:110px;">three</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for SCSS or LESS. It have mixins, variables, etc, and it autocompile real and long css. It was maded to this purposes and write less and less css with the same result.

http://sass-lang.com/guide

http://lesscss.org/

```
 @size: 10px;
 .class { font-size: @size;  }
```

Good luck!

Comment: i'm familiar with that, but still, you must define all variables inside the file. I was wondering if you can pass values dynamically.

Comment: It is impossible. The only method is by javascript injected code, and is the same that people said in his answers: inline css.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to directly pass parameters using just CSS but you're not the first person to ask - check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893823/how-to-pass-parameters-to-css-classes) which looks at CSS and JavaScript options and also [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) might be helpful regarding attribute selection.

This will only help if you are looking at a few variables of `margin-top` but I don't know what context you're using this in. Depending on what you're using it for there might be better ways.

The simplest way would probably be just to add the style inline to your span `<span style="margin-top:10px">` but I try to stay away from inline CSS!

Answer (score -1):

no your code is wrong 
but you can write css inside the tag

```
*<span style="margin-top:Xpx;">*
```

Comment: there's 3 methods to use css 1-in the head like <span id="a"> and inside the head <style> #a{ color:red;}</style>      2-in another file and we include it in the head like that <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">     or just write your code inside your tag like this <span style="color:red;font-family:italic">