# Pass a value from HTML to CSS

Tags: html, css, variables, styles, less

I was interested whether can I pass value to the css class from the html?
Like this
Example:

```
<div class="mt(5)"> Some text </div>
style {
 .mt(@mpx) {
   margin-top: @mpx px;
 }
}
```

I've heard that such way was possible in Less

Comment: Since you mentioned  [**less**](http://lesscss.org/), did you research about it?

Comment: This  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893823/how-to-pass-parameters-to-css-classes) may regard your concern

Comment: ... Why not just do `<div style="margin-top:5px">`? If you're going to use a class to apply a single style, and then make it a variable passed in by the HTML, you might as well just use inline styles. Or you could do things properly.

Comment: First of all I want to minimize the code and write it in nicely. I can't use inline styles at all because it is not good solution. For margins and paddings I want different styles: ml-1 > margin-left:5; mb-2 > margin-bottom:10; and so on. So I don't want to write all the cases by hard code.

Comment: *I've heard that such way was possible in Less* - No, it's not (Neither CSS, nor Less, nor any other CSS-preprocessor). You'll need some script to achieve the goal.

Comment: If you are using React, then styled components are a way to do this. They can take props (ie arguments).

Answer (score 19):

No, the way you want it is impossible in either CSS or any of its supersets (like Less and others). It's always HTML that uses values from CSS and not in opposite. Thus you'll need some scripting for what you need.

You *can* however pass values from HTML to CSS via [Custom Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) using inline styles:

```css
.c {color:  var(--c)}
.m {margin: var(--m)}
```

```html
<div class="c" style="--c: blue" >Foo</div>
<div class="m" style="--m: 0 2em">Bar</div>
<div class="c" style="--c: green">Baz</div>
```

Or even like this:

```css
* {
    color:  var(--c);
    margin: var(--m);
    /* etc. */
}
```

```html
<div style="--c: blue" >Foo</div>
<div style="--m: 0 2em">Bar</div>
<div style="--c: green">Baz</div>
```

But that method is *no way* different from styling by the plain vanilla method, i.e.:

```
<div style="color: blue"> 
... etc.
```

It is essentially same ugly and non-maintainable.

---

> Many people try to achieve the goal by generating hundreds of predefined classes like `.mt-1`, `.mt-2`, ... `.mt-99` etc. (since it's extremely easy thing to do in a CSS-preprocessor). But it's even more ugly solution (I won't bother you with details on why it is so. You'll read about that elsewhere or learn yourself after a few projects).

Comment: Pretty sure this is what the OP was looking for.  It was for me!  Thanks!  Learned something new today!

Comment: Just want to throw this out there.  IE is not supported with this approach, not too big of a deal, but wanted to alert peeps of this.

Comment: @IamBatman What is IE? Well, speaking seriously, I treat this my answer as an example of *"Never Do This"* rather than a suggested solution (Did you miss "It is essentially same ugly and non-maintainable." in the end?) The very idea of trying to use CSS as in the Q shows a misunderstanding of the CSS design as a whole.

Comment: IE = Internet Explorer (unless your being sarcastic as IE is an ancient browser).  Yeah I saw that, but I have 3 elements that have the same styling except the color and instead of using 3 different classes I wanted to use a variable of some sort.  This solved my issue.  Now technically I guess I could just override the CSS with individual element styles and that would make more sense to be compatible with IE.

Answer (score 9):

Maybe this is what you looking for? [CSS: Attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr())

You can bind the value to an attribute and then get this attribute back in the css, like this:

**CSS**

```
<p data-foo="hello">world</p>
```

**CSS**

```
[data-foo]::before {
    content: attr(data-foo) " ";
}
```

**Result**

> hello world

Comment: **note:** for the time being, only string attributes are widely supported. all other types (integer, etc...) are experimental.  
  
**source**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

Comment: Promising! This would mean the sea of classes which all represent 1 style rule (like tailwind) will become history.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way of doing that **without** the use of LESS.

1. Use CSS variables:
   Variables can be declared in the `style` attribute of the HTML elements.
   Then, the CSS will catch the values from the HTML and apply the correct styles.
2. Add some JavaScript:
   The values of the variables can now be dynamically modified.

⋅ ⋅ ⋅

Example of use:

- Background color is set in the HTML, (fixed)
- Padding of div1 will grow if clicked. (dynamic)

```js
// When clicking on the div1, padding is gonna grow up.
document.getElementById("div1").onclick = function(){
  var pad = this.style.getPropertyValue("--pad");
  this.style.setProperty("--pad", parseInt(pad) + 1);
}
```

```css
.divs {
  background: var(--bg);
  padding: calc(var(--pad)*5px);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="divs" style="--bg: #ff6; --pad: 1;">div1</div>
<div id="div2" class="divs" style="--bg: #f66; --pad: 2;">div2</div>
```

⋅ ⋅ ⋅

About CSS variables:
The variable names must begin with `--` and are case sensitive.
These variables values are applied to the element and its children.
To use it globally, you can declare it on the body tag.

Here is a link with some examples: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp

Comment: Yes I found defining variables topic, but that was not thing I was needed. It was interesting tho. I want to pass variables dynamically.

Comment: @KoboldMines What do you mean by "dynamically" ? (CSS variables can be accessed with javascript/jQuery)

Comment: I mean passing values from HTML and catching them in css. I work with angular project, can't use jQuery.

Comment: @KoboldMines I added an example of JavaScript (without jQuery) that modifies a CSS variable.