# Angular Mat Datepicker - Apply styles dynamically

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, datepicker

I have a Datepicker component which contains a Material Datepicker. This component receives a `datepickerConfig` object describing how the Datepicker should be styled. For example, this object describes what level of shadow to apply, the focus styles, hover styles, etc.

I'm quite new to Material styling so I'm wondering how I can apply these styles dynamically, during runtime?

As an example, for the shadow, I have declared the following variables in my SCSS file:

```
/* shadow */
$shadow-opacity: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
$dp-box-shadow-mobile: 0 30px 40px $shadow-opacity;
$dp-box-shadow-desktop-1: 0 3px 6px $shadow-opacity;
$dp-box-shadow-desktop-2: 0 6px 12px $shadow-opacity;
...
// more variables for the different styles

.mat-datepicker-content {
    // dynamically apply variables to these styles
    // e.g. if datepickerConfig.shadow.level === 2 
    // then $dp-box-shadow-desktop-2 should be applied 
    box-shadow: ...; 
    border: ...;
    border-radius: ...;
    ...
}
```

During runtime, I need to check what kind of shadow level is in the `datepickerConfig` object and dynamically apply the correct style to the element.

My Datepicker template:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">    
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker (opened)="opened()">
      <mat-datepicker-actions>
        <button mat-button matDatepickerCancel>CANCEL</button>
        <button mat-raised-button matDatepickerApply>OK</button>
      </mat-datepicker-actions>
    </mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

How can I achieve this, not only for the shadow but for the multiple styles I have to dynamically set? I'm wondering about a clean way to do this with Angular... or can this only be achieved  targeting the class with JS?

Thanks.

Comment: [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) Directive may fit you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). You cannot use SCSS variables, they are not available for you in run time, because they disappear when SCSS is compiled into CSS.

[Support for CSS variables](https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20var) is now pretty good. Although IE11 is out of the game.

I've created an example in stackblitz that is dynamically changing style of a button shadow using CSS variable based on the value provided via config: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cuyhed?file=src/app/fancy-button.component.ts

Global styles contains definition of CSS variables.

*styles.css*

```css
    :root {
     /* shadow-opacity variables, that will be used based on the configuration */
      --shadow-opacity-level-1: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
      --shadow-opacity-level-2: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

      /* default shadow opacity */
      --shadow-opacity: var(--shadow-opacity-level-1);
    }

    /* global styles for a fancy-button, similar to your .mat-datepicker-content class */
    .fancy-button {
      border: 3px solid;
      padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
      /* here we use var(--shadow-opacity) to set default value, --shadow-opacity will be overridden later, based on the current configuration  */
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px 0px var(--shadow-opacity);
    }
```

Next we need a button component, that is using `.fancy-button` class, but also overrides value of `--shadow-opacity` variable based on the current configuration value.

The `getButtonStyle()` method checks the `config.shadowLevel` value and will set `--shadow-opacity` variable to appropriate shadow level.

*fancy-button.component.ts*

```typescript
    @Component({
      selector: 'fancy-button',
      template: `
        <button 
          class="fancy-button"
          style="{{getButtonStyle()}}"
        >
          {{config.label}}
        </button>
      `,
      styles: [``]
    })
    export class FancyButtonComponent  {
      @Input() config: FancyButtonConfig;

      getButtonStyle(): string {
        if (this.config.shadowLevel === 1) {
          return '--shadow-opacity: var(--shadow-opacity-level-1)';
        }

        if (this.config.shadowLevel === 2) {
          return '--shadow-opacity: var(--shadow-opacity-level-2)';
        }

        throw Error(`Unknown shadowLevel: ${this.config.shadowLevel}`);
      }
    }
```

Wrapping up

There is also option to use custom classes and overrides, as Nathan suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70355520/1212547). I think CSS variables and classes overrides are quite equivalent approaches and when deciding between those two I would go with an approach that will produce cleaner and a better maintainable code.

**Resources**

- [Introduction to CSS Variables by Kevin Powell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PHO6TBq_auI)
- [Overriding "parameter" of CSS class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51461602/1212547)

---

**Answer extended with Angular Material component**

Question was asking specifically about Angular material component, but answer above describes regular HTML button.

I've extended stackblitz demo with `FancyButtonMatWrapperComponent` that wraps [`mat-raised-button`](https://v12.material.angular.io/components/button/overview) and changing its `box-shadow` based on provided configuration.

All the mechanics work as described above for regular HTML button. The main difference is, that outer `div` in index.html has class `material-overrides` which is helping with overriding the default Angular Material styles.

Global `styles.css` then contains following overrides

```css
    .material-overrides .mat-raised-button {
      border: 3px solid black;
      padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px 0px 0px var(--shadow-opacity);
    }
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I ended up doing. Although, I did have to resort to Angular's `Renderer2` to apply the CSS vars on the `documentElement`, in the OnInit hook. 
E.g. `this.renderer.setStyle(this.doc.documentElement, '--dp-box-shadow', boxShadow, RendererStyleFlags2.DashCase)`.
This was needed since `cdk-overlay` is injected near the top of the tree which was preventing me from applying the styles directly into a datepicker div wrapper (since I can't access all the mat elements I want through the template).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it would be great if you could add the renderer solution to your answer, I'm sure it would be helpful to a lot of people!

Comment: Cool, thanks for suggestion, once I got little time will have a look at how to use this approach with Angular Material component and will update the stackblitz example with `Renderer2` and update the answer.

Comment: I've extended the demo with Angular Material button, but eventually I didn't use `Renderer2` to set style of CSS variable. As you can see I've used class `material-overrides` to bump specificity of custom styles over material styles. For more complex material components, like the datepicker, the overrides in global styles would need to be more complex, but I think the approach should work the same way. Please let me know if this would work also for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [[ngStyle] directive](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#ngstyle) -- take this example which dynamically sets a width property based on a condition.

```
  <div [style.width.%]="condition ? 20 : 50" ...>
```

Using `[ngStyle]` or the "cleaner" alternative syntax above can get messy once you start managing multiple styles and can't really be used to get at projected content not available in the template.

I might suggest using a class approach instead (with [[ngClass] attribute directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)) and using a SCSS override to conditionally reset some properties.

```
<mat-form-field class="datepicker"
                [class.datepicker--modified]="condition">
...

// in the SCSS
.datepicker {
  color: red;

  &--modified {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```