# Setting css class with variable in Xaringan with remark.js

Tags: css, xaringan, remarkjs

I often need to change dynamically the font size or other properties for xaringan slides. Instead of defining a lot of different CSS classes I would like to define a general `fontsize` class and then passing a `%` value as variable. Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17894116/9032257:

```
# Header 1

.fontsize50[
- some text
- some text
]
```

But fontisize50 is not hard coded on the CSS file. Is that possible?

## Update

I have tried to use the approach proposed on Remark documentation https://github.com/gnab/remark/issues/72#issuecomment-62225566. I am able to dynamically the font size of a single word but not applying the `font-size` property to an entire section.

Adding this function to a `macro.js` file and setting the `beforeInit` YAML:

```js
remark.macros.fontsize = function (size = "100%") {
  var txt = this;
  tag = "<span style=" + "'font-size:" + size + "'>" + txt + "</span>";
  return tag
};
```

Then using this:

```
# Header 1

<!-- This Works -->

Hello ![:fontsize 200%](World)!

<!-- This Not -->

Hello ![:fontsize 200%](

- bullet 1
- bullet 2
- bullet 3

)
```

Change the fontsize according to the percentage only in the first case. I would like to have the same behavior as having a CSS class:

```css
.font50 {
   font-size: 50%;
}
```

And then using:

```
Hello

.font50[

- bullet 1
- bullet 2
- bullet 3

]
```

But I am not able to do this.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. This is essentially the same issue as https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/360.

Comment: Thank you @YihuiXie. I have tried to use this approach https://github.com/gnab/remark/issues/72#issuecomment-62225566 but I am able to only change a single word or a piece of text but not adding a CSS class to an entire section as using `.[]`. I'll update my question maybe it is useful to someone